# Where to upload the .bin file to install ColdFusion

Tags: ubuntu, coldfusion, ubuntu-server

I have upload the `.bin` file to install *ColdFusion* on *Ubuntu* in the *root* directory. However, when I run the code to install the file, the file is not found.

Could you please tell me where exactly I need to upload the file.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not really a 'coding' question. This would probably be better served at ServerFault.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the installation file where ever you like on the server. When you run the command to install it you specify where that file is.

*Disclaimer: I have not tried this but just did a quick web search to find the information*

The steps seem to be documented fairly well here - [Install ColdFusion 11 on Ubuntu](https://medium.com/@rhpt/install-coldfusion-11-on-ubuntu-66d2efdf03a2#.28cj9lxws) (Even if you are not installing version 11 the steps should still apply.)

In answer to your specific question here type the following command in the console:

> sudo ./ColdFusion_11_WWE_linux64.bin

That assumes the installation file is in the root directory.

There are several other requirements needed before ColdFusion will be setup; `libstdc++5 be installed` needs to be installed, you may want `Apache2` installed (or some other web server), etc.

Read over the page that I referenced. It should get you going. There is a lot of information on the internet about this. Here is a link to Adobe's [Installing the Server Configuration](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/installing/installing-the-server-configuration.html) documentation. And here is a list of [supported environments for ColdFusion 11](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/coldfusion/pdfs/cf11/coldfusion11-support-matrix.pdf) and for [ColdFusion 2016](https://helpx.adobe.com/pdf/coldfusion2016-support-matrix.pdf).